# opening multiple textboxes using javascript based on value entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

suppose i am having a textbox

```
  <input type="text" name="fnames" />
    <input type="submit" value="save" name="save" onclick="open()" />


   <script type="text/javascript">
      function open()
      {

       }

         </script>
```

what i am trying to do is that when i enter a number say 7 in the textbox and click submit then it should call the javascript function and should open 7 textboxes together  instantly....can anyone help me in this regard ??

Comment: its your homework better you do it, even try at least

Comment: i tried but lacking somewhere i guess...not getting an idea where to start from

Comment: start from learning javascript

Comment: Whay you mean with "opening textboxes"? A new window containing 7 textboxes...?

Comment: not in  a new window but on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The `open()` function in javascript is reserved:

```
function makeBoxes(){
    // parseInt makes sure that the number entered not gets treated like a string
    var numberOfBoxes=parseInt(document.getElementById('fnames').value, 10);
    var boxesHTML="";
    var boxesString="<input type='text' />"
    for (var i=1; i<=numberOfBoxes; i++){
        boxesHTML+=boxesString;
    }
    document.getElementById('parentElementIdWhereYouWantTheBoxes').innerHTML=boxesHTML;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8qyH/2/

Comment: Rookie mistake ><. Fixed :)

Comment: Yup. Added the `=` in `for (var i=1; i<=numberOfBoxes; i++)`. Which would give it one more iteration :)

Comment: i applied this code but when i am clicking the button it is opening the textboxes but getting vanished within a second too....why is this thing happening??

Comment: You need to change `type='submit'` to `type='button'` on the save-button. And set `id='fnames'` on the first textbox :)

Comment: Submit makes it refreshing the page. Also the `open()` function is already used in javascript. I've made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/e8qyH/2/